# Why using cin before sync_with_stdio(false) give random values to next i/p variable

Tags: c++, synchronization, stdio

This is a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
int t,n;cin>>t;

cin.tie(NULL);


while(t--){

    cin>>n;
    cout<<n<<endl;
}
}
```

If I give input as

```
2
1
2
```

I get ouput `1` `2`(in new line) as expected.
Now if I use `cin>>t` before `ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`. Then for the same i/p, o/p is `0` `0`(in new line).

AFAIK: `ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` stops the sync with `c++` and `c` `i/p` `o/p`, but I am using `cin` in both the cases, why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this behavior is implementation-defined.

> If this function(Here it refers to sync_with_stdio) is called after I/O has occurred on the standard stream, the behavior is implementation-defined: implementations range from no effect to destroying the read buffer.